# DAS 3.0.1 Event Publisher gives an error while trying to publish Output Event rdbms to API Manager 1.10

Tags: wso2-das

```
[2016-03-17 15:46:52,955] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.internal.OutputAdapterRuntime} -  Event dropped at Output Adapter 'REQUEST_SUMMARY' for tenant id '-1234', null
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.rdbms.RDBMSEventAdapter.initializeDatabaseExecutionInfo(RDBMSEventAdapter.java:226)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.rdbms.RDBMSEventAdapter.publish(RDBMSEventAdapter.java:132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.internal.OutputAdapterRuntime.publish(OutputAdapterRuntime.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.internal.CarbonOutputEventAdapterService.publish(CarbonOutputEventAdapterService.java:143)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.EventPublisher.process(EventPublisher.java:361)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.EventPublisher.sendEvent(EventPublisher.java:209)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.EventPublisher.consumeEvent(EventPublisher.java:275)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.stream.core.internal.EventJunction.sendEvent(EventJunction.java:142)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.management.InputEventDispatcher.onEvent(InputEventDispatcher.java:27)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.EventReceiver.sendEvent(EventReceiver.java:259)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.EventReceiver.processTypedEvent(EventReceiver.java:241)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.EventReceiver$TypedEventSubscription.onEvent(EventReceiver.java:317)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.core.internal.InputAdapterRuntime.onEvent(InputAdapterRuntime.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.wso2event.internal.ds.WSO2EventAdapterServiceDS$1.receive(WSO2EventAdapterServiceDS.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)